# When is Naruto using Kurama one tail

Tags: naruto

In which episode is Naruto using Kurama one tail mode for the first time?

Answer (score 4):

Naruto first manifested a one-tail chakra in manga **Chapter 231**, which is **Episode 133** *A Plea from a Friend* in the anime. This is during Naruto and Sasuke's fight as Naruto tries to stop Sasuke from leaving the village. If I recall correctly, there were no other similar occurrences preceding this.